# US citizen working for a US company. I want to live in Honduras

Tags: us-citizens, working

I am a US citizen, and I work for a US Company. I want to live in Honduras because I work on the internet . Can this be done even on a temporary basis? I have been away from my wife for 3 months and I want to be able to spend time with her in Honduras and work for my current US company online.

Comment: Is your wife a citizen of Honduras?

Answer (score 1):

One important consideration is that just because you say "I work on the internet", that doesn't mean that the Honduras government won't treat that as "working".

I know this is the case in Thailand (where I live as an expat), where any kind of work that is done while in Thailand counts as "working in Thailand".

While this might seem to be a trivial unimportant detail to the person doing the work, as far as the government is concerned you might be liable for income tax. So "working on the internet" while in a country, can constitute "working" in that country, and mean that you need to pay income tax in that country.

I don't know that Honduras is like this - it might not be. But be aware that it is distinctly possible. And while you might think it's not something important, they could easily see it as tax evasion. Make sure you are aware of the local laws before attempting to work in a foreign country. Work permits and tax might be involved.